# Combining XML data with data type information from XML Schema

Tags: python, ruby, xml, schema

I would like to automate creating a flat list/array type structure in a language such as Ruby,Python etc that takes XML data and for each node builds a list/array entry that contains the data plus data type information obtained from its XML Schema.

Any pointers to a solution appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? `nokogiri` in Ruby, for example? (As a bonus, [a tweet by Jeff](https://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/121881520641277952).)

Comment: have the same problem, lxml validation does not help

Answer (score 0):

In python, there are several xml parsing libraries, but I'd recommend [lxml](http://lxml.de/). Then, it's a piece of cake. Just iterate through your xml and this way you have access to data, attributes etc. Filling a list out of them is trivial. Just a little experimentation...

Comment: I am not sure how traversing the XML file references the data types from XML Schema file though?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry to sound like a numpty but I can only see examples of how it validates against the Schema but not how to extract the Schema information during a traverse of the XML data.